# ¿Como saber si un textbox.text es numero o caracter en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

quiero saber si es numero o letra el textbox que introduzca por teclado

```
 if (txtCodigo.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("son numeros");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("son letras");
                }
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Talvés usar regex? ¿o alguna validación caracter por caracter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias implementar algo como ser

```
int temp = 0;

if (int.TryParse(txtCodigo.Text, out temp))
{
    MessageBox.Show("son numeros");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("son letras");
}
```

cuando intenta parsear a numerico el `TryParse()` retorna un true/false que puede usar para conocer si es un numero valido o no

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) para ver si la conversión a entero del texto es posible. Si lo es,es un valor numérico. Si no, texto:

```
int valorNumerico = 0;

if (int.TryParse(txtCodigo.Text,out valorNumerico))
{
    //numero
}
else
{
    //no numero
}
```